# Pyspark : User defined elasticity for each unique id

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working on a price elasticity problem where i need to calculate the elasticity for each unique id

My dataframe looks like

```
| id    | price  | items | 

| 101   |  5     | 10    |   
| 101   |  10    | 15    | 
| 101   |  12    | 20    | 
| 102   |  1     | 1     | 
| 102   |  3     | 7     |
```

To find the elasticity:
consider the example of 101, there are 3 changes in prices happening, these three price changes and the corresponding items change should be the new dataframe.

1) price change of 5 (5 -> 10 (or 10 -> 5)) resulted in 5 item change (10 -> 15 (or 15 -> 10)) so corresponding row would be pricechange =5, itemschange=5

2) price change of 7 (5 -> 12 (or 12 -> 5)) resulted in 10 item change (10 -> 20 (or 20 -> 10)) so corresponding row would be pricechange =7, itemschange=10

3) price change of 2 (10 -> 12 (or 12 -> 10) ) resulted in 5 item change (15 -> 20 (or 20 -> 15)) so corresponding row would be pricechange =2, itemschange=5

The dataframe would be transformed to:

```
| id    | pricechange  | itemschange | 

| 101   |  5           | 5           |   
| 101   |  7           | 10          | 
| 101   |  2           | 5           | 
| 102   |  2           | 6           |
```

Comment: spark DataFrames are unordered. how are you determining which is the "first" row and what is the "next" row? You can not simply rely on the order in the file or as displayed- you need to specify it yourself.

Comment: Simply changing the words does not solve the issue. You're implicitly implying that the prices changes from 5 to 10 in the first example. How do you determine that 5 comes first and 10 is next? Why can't it be 10 -> 5 (spark has no idea unless you tell it).

Comment: All the combinations are considered here. In your scenario of 10 coming first and 5 coming next, the absolute difference is still 5. so the price change is still 5

Comment: Ok that makes sense- you should [edit] your question to clarify that you only care about the absolute difference. Anyway, seems like this can be solved using a simple inner join. Join the dataframe to itself on `id` and the compute the price changes and item changes. Have you tried that?

Comment: I have tried that but it results in duplicate rows. Can you please let me know the procedure to handle duplicate rows? By duplicate rows i mean 10 -> 5 is available and also 5 -> 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do an inner join of the DataFrame with itself on the `id` column. To avoid duplicate records, define a `where` clause that requires the left DataFrame's price to be greater than that of the right DataFrame.

After the join, select the desired columns:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df.alias("r").join(df.alias("l"), on="id")\
    .where("l.price > r.price")\
    .select(
        "id",
        (col("l.price") - col("r.price")).alias("pricechange"),
        (col("l.item") - col("r.item")).alias("itemschange"),
    ).show()
#+---+-----------+-----------+
#| id|pricechange|itemschange|
#+---+-----------+-----------+
#|101|          2|          5|
#|101|          7|         10|
#|101|          5|          5|
#|102|          2|          6|
#+---+-----------+-----------+
```

This will be more efficient than using a `Window`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the detailed approach you can follow -

Define Schema and prepare data for DF

```
 df = spark.createDataFrame([
            (101,5,10),
            (101,10,15),
            (101,12,20),
            (102,1,1),    
            (102,3,7)
        ],'id : int, price : int, item: int')
```

Create dummy column rank to compare each id with all other records of same id

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

windowSpec = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('id')
rank = row_number().over(windowSpec).alias('rank')

df = df.withColumn("rank", rank)
```

Final logic - Join and Filter

```
df.alias('a').\
    join(df.alias('b'),on='id').\
    where('a.rank < b.rank').\
    selectExpr("a.id as id","b.price - a.price as price","b.item - a.item as item").\
    show()
```

IMHO - It's always better to post what you tried so far and what error/issue your are facing along with the question. This help to get quick and better response.